# Finding alternative to ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I am applying ng-model on textarea, but it is showing error in ie 11. My code is as follows.

```
<div ng-hide="DoctorDashboardCtrl.showEducation">
      <textarea placeholder="2000 Characters Free flow text" width="832px" height="100px" class="form-control" ng-model="DoctorDashboardCtrl.otherdetails.education">
             <!-- {{DoctorDashboardCtrl.otherdetails.education}} -->       
      </textarea>
</div>
```

After getting error as invalid argument in ie11. I changed the code to

```
<div ng-hide="DoctorDashboardCtrl.showEducation">
     <textarea placeholder="2000 Characters Free flow text" width="832px" height="100px" class="form-control" ng-bind="DoctorDashboardCtrl.otherdetails.education"> 
           {{DoctorDashboardCtrl.otherdetails.education}} 
     </textarea>
</div>
```

But now, after cicking on save button when I printed value of DoctorDashboardCtrl.otherdetails.education, it is not getting updated and instead it is showing old value. Is there any other solution to this or do I have to work with the error coming forever?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: can you share your controller code?

Comment: @str Error: Invalid argument.
   at interpolateFnWatchAction (https://localhost:8443/assets/lib/angular/angular.js:9430:17)
   at interpolateFnWatcher (https://localhost:8443/assets/lib/angular/angular.js:12020:17)
   at watchGroupAction (https://localhost:8443/assets/lib/angular/angular.js:16539:13)
   at Scope.prototype.$digest (https://localhost:8443/assets/lib/angular/angular.js:16869:23)
   at Scope.prototype.$apply (https://localhost:8443/assets/lib/angular/angular.js:17133:13)
   at done 
   at completeRequest 
   at requestLoaded

Comment: @Thinker https://docs.google.com/a/valueaddsofttech.com/document/d/1AqvhTBY4Nr0bA8J-KDw4fXLCHzCSXTVzs4HUqJgVcLg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @GauravBhusare try using plnkr or jsfiddle to test code, not google docs :)

Comment: @NirbhayTandon I was showing a single function out of huge code that's why din't used plunker or fiddle.. thanks for your suggestion I will follow from next time

Answer (score 0):

@Gaurav: Add a watch in your code, so that you will get updated value

```
`$scope.$watch(
            function(){
                return $scope.otherdetails.education;
            },
            function(newValue, oldValue){
                if(newValue && newValue != oldValue) {
                    $scope.otherdetails.education = newValue;
                }
            },
            true
        );`
```

and also assign empty array and string at the starting of your controller:

`$scope.otherdetails = [];
$scope.otherdetails.education = "";`

Comment: otherdetails is an object in my case. I tried your sol but its not working

Comment: yes neha this code is working perfectly fine. but if you try to run this fiddle in Internet explorer it will show you an error, code will work. Justkeep you console open.

Comment: Do not worry about console errors that is not related to the code. You can give a try. Let me know if you face any issue.